# iterate over spacy tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

A simple question that has me stumped. I want to iterate over spacy tokens and compare every token to all the tokens for similarity with an iterator, rather than a for loop. The problem is a bit like having a list of numbers [1, 2, 3] and trying to multiply every number by every other number including itself, giving [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]. Instead I have:

```
import spacy
import itertools
nlp = spacy.load('en')

tokens = nlp(u'dog cat banana')

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        print(token1.similarity(token2))
```

The nested for loops work, but there should be a way of using an iterator for cleaner code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension solution would be:

```
[token1.similarity(token2) for token1 in tokens for token2 in tokens]
```

or

```
[token1.similarity(token2) for token1, token2 in itertools.product(tokens, tokens)]
```